# compare two multidimensional arrays of object and set new property true/false pending match on larger set

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I Have an array of objects example:

Larger Set:

```
Array(
    [0] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => monkey,
                        [sub] => help
                       ),
    [1] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => tooth,
                        [sub] => tip
                       ),
    [2] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => who,
                        [sub] => knows
                       ),
    )
```

Smaller Set

```
Array(
    [0] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => monkey,
                        [sub] => help
    )
```

Desired out come:

```
Array(
    [0] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => monkey,
                        [sub] => help,
                        [selected] => yes
                       ),
    [1] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => tooth,
                        [sub] => tip,
                        [selected] => no
                       ),
    [2] stdClass Object(
                        [ID] => 1,
                        [name] => who,
                        [sub] => knows,
                        [selected] => no
                       ),
    )
```

What I am trying to play with which doesn't seem to be working is

```
    foreach($result_static as $stock)
    {
        foreach($result_memb as $memb_choice)
        {
            $stock->selected = "false";
            //echo $stock->name .' == '. $memb_choice->name.'<br>';
            if($stock->name == $memb_choice->name)
            {
                $stock->selected = "yes";
            }
        }
        $output[] = $stock;
    }
```

This doesn't appear to be matching any of the actual results, and from what I gather my foreach logic is off cause either due to it relooping the second loop so many times or the first one withing the other this way, the names from each never match respectively the way I would hope. So I am trying to look for ideas on how to better tackle this, and hopefully something a bit more optimized would be nice, but Ill take what I can get currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
foreach($result_static as $stock)
    {
        $stock->selected = "false";
        foreach($result_memb as $memb_choice)
        {
            if($stock->name == $memb_choice->name)
            {
                $stock->selected = "yes";
            }
        }
        $output[] = $stock;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was unable to find the bug in your code, maybe it is somewhere else?

I have tried to re-create it, and the following code runs and gives the desired output:

```
class Item
{
    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Sub;
    public $Selected;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $sub)
    {
        $this->Id = $id;
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Sub = $sub;
    }
}

$result_static  = array(
    new Item(1, 'monkey', 'help'),
    new Item(1, 'tooth', 'tip'),
    new Item(1, 'who', 'known')
);

$result_memb  = array(new Item(1, 'monkey', 'help'));

$output = array();

foreach($result_memb  as $memb_choice)
{
    foreach($result_static  as $stock)
    {
        $stock->Selected = "false";

        if($stock->Name == $memb_choice->Name)
        {
            $stock->Selected = "yes";
        }
        $output[] = $stock;
     }
 }

 print_r($output);
```

This gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => monkey
            [Sub] => help
            [Selected] => yes
        )

    [1] => Item Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => tooth
            [Sub] => tip
            [Selected] => false
        )

    [2] => Item Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => who
            [Sub] => known
            [Selected] => false
        )
)
```